# Система достижений/заданий в игре

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

В процессе учебы пишу игру на собирание слов из букв, аналоги есть, но точно такой нет, придумал свои особенности. Дошел до создания задач, написал к ним метрики, но как их реализовать не понимаю, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Например есть некий список задач:

```
ArrayList<String> Task = new ArrayList<>();

Task.add("Собрать слово из 3 букв 3 раза");
Task.add("Собрать слово из 4 букв 3 раза");
Task.add("Последовательность: каждое новое слово длиннее предыдущего, 3 раза");
Task.add("Последовательность: каждое новое слово длиннее предыдущего, 4 раза");
....
....
```

Счетчики количества слов и т.д. (для простоты не указывал в примере get\set):

```
int length_3 = 0;
int length_4 = 0;
int sequence_3 = 0;
int sequence_4 = 0;
....
....
```

Статистика (кол-во правильных не правильных слов), длинна слов, рост очков от собранных слов и прочее завязано на кнопку проверки.

Я пытаюсь сделать универсальный метод или как-то еще проверять правильность выполненных задач. Есть задача правильная, она передается в список, который будет отображаться в разделе "выполненные" `ArrayList<String> TaskDone = new ArrayList<>();` и за каждую выполненную задачу будет начисляться какое-то кол-во очков.

Это слишком сложно или я слишком туплю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы писал все результата игр с их деталями в "лог", а потом по нему проверял правилами достижений. В таком случае:

- четкое разделение ролей (есть хранилище, есть правила)
- система не имеет состояния (кроме лога)
- правила легко дополнять и обновлять (1 метод = 1 правило)
- ачивки легко пересчитывать
- вы можете записывать логи и/или отправлять себе на сервер для истории и анализа

Comment: Kromster, идея интересная, спасибо!  Я так понимаю виде лога выступает ArrayLIst, который сравниваем с другим списком с набором ачивок?

Comment: Зависит от проекта. В моем случае это БД для хранения записей и метод пробегающей по ней со списком "правил". У вас, если ачивки ограничены 1 игрой, это может быть и просто лист в памяти, да. Бонус в том, что правила могут быть более сложными, чем простое И. Например, секретная ачивка за сбор слов из 3+14+15+9 слов 14 Марта (день числа Пи).